# Has there been a spike in the birth rate in Germany?

Tags: data-request, germany, demographics

About 40 weeks ago Germany won the FIFA World Cup. At the time I thought there would be a noticeable jump in the Birth Rate there. I've been searching for current information but I can only find statistics as of 2014.

April 5 would have been 40 weeks after the world Cup win. **I'd like to know when 2015 birth rate data is available**, so I can see if there been a spike in the birth rate in Germany.

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate question for this stack exchange site. Maybe if it were rewritten as something like "how long does it take for German population statistics to be published?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much too early to carry out this analysis today. As you say, the 40 weeks period has just passed by. You should not expect the data to be ready in real-time. I am even surprised that you have already found data for 2014. I had a quick look at the two authoritative sources for this kind of data.

At the time of writing this answer, Destatis, the Federal Statistical Office of Germany, has only [data up to 2013](https://www.destatis.de/EN/FactsFigures/SocietyState/Population/Population.html).

Eurostat, the statistical office of the European Union, has [monthly data on live births](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/population-demography-migration-projections/births-fertitily-data/database). For Germany it has data for January to April 2014. But these figures are flagged as “forecast”.

As a conclusion I think that you will have to wait some more months before you can do this analysis.

Comment: Interview a bunch of [Hebammen](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=hebamme) (midwives) and they could probably give an anecdotal answer. [Here is their union.](https://www.hebammenverband.de/) in case you want to ask ;)